# Add a side-effect to Java Stream after each element is consumed?

Tags: java, java-stream

This is a simplified example but it illustrates the point.

Let's say I have a method defined like this:

```java
Stream<String> generateStream() {
  return Stream.of("hello", "world"); // (S)
}
```

Is there a way to make `S` for example print something *after* an element has been consumed without the consumer of the stream having to do or know anything about it?

For example, I'd to modify `S` so that this:

```java
generateStream().forEach(System.out::println)
```

actually prints out this to the console:

```
hello
consumed
world
consumed
```

Is this possible in Java 8 and if so how?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: I can use "peek" to print the string to the console but I want to string ("consumed") to be printed "automatically" without the consumer having to use peek. And it must be done _after_ the value has been consumed. Sort of like an @After aspect in aspectj.

Comment: The stream or the producer cannot know when a part has been consumed, because there is no such signal going back from the consumer to the producer. You can only watch the data flowing. Also think about buffering. The producer may be finished while the consumer is processing buffered content for a long time after that. You know that effect possibly from the progress bar of your file manager when you copy data onto an USB stick.

Comment: @Stefan I think your comment would make a fine answer then :)

Comment: The intent seems to add a `Consumer` to every type of terminal operation, is that right? How would that settle with the existing separation of concern each terminal operation persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` with a close action:

```
Stream<String> generateStream() {
  return Stream.of("hello", "world")
      .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s).onClose(() -> System.out.println(s+" consumed")));
}
```

which works as intended:

```
generateStream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
hello
hello consumed
world
world consumed
```

even for short-circuiting operations:

```
Optional<String> o = generateStream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("he")).findFirst();
o.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("found "+s));
```

```
hello consumed
found hello
```

But note that this can have a dramatic impact on the performance, compared to an operation without `flatMap`. But for debugging purposes, or for cases where performance doesn’t matter, it might be helpful.

Further, keep in mind that being consumed by the Stream pipeline doesn’t imply that the terminal operation won’t keep a reference to it nor stop accessing it.

It works that way for the `forEach` operation, but e.g., for `reduce((a,b) -> a)`, all elements get consumed one after the other, but a reference to the first element will be kept until the end and even returned as final result. For `min​(comparator)`, any element might be held until a smaller one has been encountered. And finally, operations like `toArray()` hold and return all elements in the result.

Also, stateful operations may detach the subsequent pipeline processing from the source stream. E.g. a `sorted` step may act like a `toArray`, buffering all elements making them appear as consumed to the source, before sorting the array and continuing by streaming over the array. Likewise, `distinct` will hold references to objects beyond their consumption and in a parallel stream, their subsequent processing might be deferred to a point after closing the source stream.

Answer (score 1):

you can use peek in your chain to consume an element and return a Stream.
forEach is closing the stream

```
    Stream.of("hello", "world")
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .forEach(word -> System.out.println("consumed"));
```

or you can chain consumers in foreach to have your expected behaviour.
Stream doesn't have an explicit method in the api for what you are asking,
you can chain methods using peek instead of foreach to not finish the stream, or chain consumer in foreach

```
    Consumer<String> stringConsumer = System.out::println;
    Consumer<String> endConsumed = string -> System.out.println("consumed");
    Stream.of("hello", "world")
            .forEach(stringConsumer.andThen(endConsumed));
```